# Rails add record based on many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 model,and their relation is `many-to-many`

MMem:

```
class MMem < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :t_mem_task_records
   has_many :m_tasks,through: :t_mem_task_records
end
```

TMemTaskRecord:

```
class TMemTaskRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :m_mem
  belongs_to :m_task
end
```

TMemTask:

```
class TMemTask < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :t_mem_task_records
   has_many :m_mems,through: :t_mem_task_records
end
```

If I want to get all `TMemTasks` of specified `MMem`,I can write:

```
MMem.find(1).m_tasks
```

Now,I  want to add a `TMemTask` to specified `MMem`

```
MMem.find(1).m_tasks.create(MTask.find(1))
```

But I got an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<MTask:0xb822624>
```

Why I got this error? or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.create` is used to create a new `MTask`, if you want to add an existed `MTask` to the association, then use:

```
MMem.find(1).m_tasks << MTask.find(1)
```

Comment: If `TMemTaskRecord` has another field named `tip` and I want to set this to `0` when I execute `MMem.find(1).m_tasks << MTask.find(1)`,what should I do?thanks!

Comment: @HXH `MMem.find(1).t_mem_task_records.create(m_task: MTask.find(1), tip: 0)`